# setValidationGroup() expects a list of valid input names

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to send a PATCH request through cURL and i get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request Server: nginx Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2016 09:16:03 GMT Content-Type: application/problem+json Content-Length: 198 Connection: keep-alive X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.19 {"type":"http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html","title":"Internal Server Error","status":500,"detail":"setValidationGroup() expects a list of valid input names; \"\" was not found"}
```

My code:

```
sendData("2016-10-01", "2016-10-02", "1234");

function sendData($from, $to, $property){
    $data = array(
        "from" => $from,
        "to" => $to,
        "booking_id" => 3
    );
    $data = json_encode($data);
    echo $data . "<br>";
    $url = "https://api.urlhost.com/property/".$property."/avail";
    echo $url. "<br>";
    $headers = array('Authorization: Basic dGVhQGJsdW1lbnJpdmllcmEuOIT6Qmx1bQVucm17aAKyzTtyfw==','Content-Type: application/json-patch+json');
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    echo ($response) . PHP_EOL;
    //print_r(curl_getinfo($ch));
    curl_close($curl);
}
```

When i echo the data and url i get these:

```
{"from":"2016-10-01","to":"2016-10-02","booking_id":3}
https://api.urlhost.com/property/1234/avail
```

But still is giving me this error. Any suggestions why this might happen?